# Submit a form including image using spring mvc restful service

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, upload

I want to implement a restful service using spring mvc, front-end is pure javascript.

The restful service is submitting a basic form including an image. Can I use Java Image type for the DTO? Something like this:

```
@Controller
public class PersonController {
@RequestMapping(value = "xxx/yyy", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void submitForm(@RequestBody PersonDto personDto) {
    String name = personDto.getName();
    int age = personDto.getAge();
    Image image = personDto.getImage();
    service.save(xxxx);
}
}

@XmlRootElement
public class PersonDto {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    ....
    private Image image;
}
```

Could I just do something like above without using MultipartFile to upload an image? I am not sure when the request coming, the actual image can be converted to a Java Image type automatically by Spring MVC?

Comment: i dont think so that you can send Image type object over service either you have to save image locally on PC and send image location over service and save somewhere or you have to encode image like Base64 Image Encoder then send encoded data over service and convert back that data into service in java

Comment: the requirement is need to install image in database not store the file path.

Comment: then you can use the second option of encoding/decoding in base64 and store mage in DB as blob